# Compile Server with fsc in IntelliJ IDEA never finishes building

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, fsc

I've been trying to get IntelliJ building with FSC, as described here:

http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.com/2010/10/turn-fsc-fast-scala-compiling-on-in.html

I've followed all the instructions exactly to set up the Run configuration.  When I do Run, this command is issued.

```
/usr/bin/java -verbose -Denv.classpath="%CLASSPATH%" -Denv.emacs="%EMACS%" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/local/share/scala-2.8/lib/scala-compiler.jar:/opt/local/share/scala-2.8/lib/scala-library.jar scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer
```

I passed the -verbose argument, then I get to see what's being loaded.  Here are the last 10 lines of output:

```
[Loaded java.net.Socket from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded com.apple.java.Usage$3 from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded com.apple.java.Application from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded com.apple.java.Application$1 from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$ExternalData from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Variable from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Value from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$StringEnvironment from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
```

It never progresses beyond this point, even after an hour.  I'm completely new to Scala, and I know almost nothing about Java, so I don't have any clues here.  I'll be happy to supply more information if that will help, but for now, this is really all I can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you're hitting a known bug http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-2271

the workaround is to start fsc manually

there is a chance that you'll also trip over http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-2409

for this one you'd better setup a script which restarts fsc every hal an hour

Comment: I was hoping for a more convenient answer, but I accepted yours since it has been the only one and seems correct.  Thankfully the tools have progressed a lot in the last year and half, so I haven't run into this problem anymore.